# KSQLDB: Select Fields As Array

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to transform data from one topic (read-topic) to (write-topic) another via KsqlDb.

This is the data that has been producing to read-topic

```
{
  "orderNumber": "01235656",
  "deliveryBarcode": "733998877",
  "requestId": "1616516663000",
  "status": "APPROVED_BY_SUPERVISOR"
}
```

I wrote these ksqldb queries:

```
-- The general stream to read the topic is like this:
CREATE STREAM GENERAL_STREAM (
    deliveryBarcode VARCHAR,
    orderNumber VARCHAR,
    requestId VARCHAR,
    status VARCHAR
) WITH (
    kafka_topic = 'read-topic',
    value_format = 'json'
);


-- This is the stream to redirect the filtered data throgh 'write-topic'
CREATE STREAM REDIRECTION_STREAM
WITH (
    partitions = 6,
    replicas = 3,
    kafka_topic = 'write-topic',
    value_format = 'json'
) AS
SELECT
       AS_VALUE(requestId) `requestId`,
       ARRAY<STRUCT<
        deliveryBarcode 
        orderNumber
       >> `packages`
FROM EARTH_DELIVERY_COURIER_PUDOPACKAGESTATUSUPDATED_0
WHERE (payload -> status = 'APPROVED_BY_SUPERVISOR')
EMIT CHANGES;
```

But my query doesn't work because of this part:

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<
        deliveryBarcode 
        orderNumber
       >> `packages`
```

My expected data on write-topic is like this

```
{
  "requestId": "1616516663000"
  "packages":[
    {
      "ordernumber":"01235656",
      "barcodenumber":"733998877"
    }
  ]
}
```

How should I modify those queries to be able to produce the 'packages' field in an array format as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with the array() ans as_map() functions to generate the output you expect.

Here's the CSAS I used to do the trick:

```
CREATE STREAM REDIRECTION_STREAM 
WITH (kafka_topic='write_topic', value_format='json') 
AS SELECT 
  AS_VALUE(requestId) requestId, 
  ARRAY[
    AS_MAP(
      ARRAY['deliverybarcode', 'ordernumber'], 
      ARRAY[deliverybarcode, ordernumber]
    )
  ] packages 
FROM GENERAL_STREAM;
```

Here's the output of the above topic

```
print 'write_topic' from BEGINNING;
Key format: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/03/24 13:24:44.557 Z, key: <null>, value: {"REQUESTID":"1616516663000","PACKAGES":[{"ordernumber":"01235656","deliverybarcode":"733998877"}]}, partition: 0
^CTopic
```

Comment: Excellent solution Sergio. It works. Thank you!